# Как сделать отступы при вводе в инпут

Tags: vue.js

Не могу нигде найти как это реализовать, хотел реализовать после ввода двух символов идет пробел ввожу три символа идет пробел опять и так по новой, сначала идет два пробел потом опять три и пробел, нашел через replaсе, но я не могу понять куда нужно вставлять фильтр в vue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать директиву v-model.lazy для обновления значения инпута только при его потере фокуса. Затем, используя JavaScript, вы можете добавить функцию валидации, которая будет добавлять пробелы после двух или трех символов в значении инпута. Например:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input v-model.lazy="inputValue" @blur="addSpaces" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      inputValue: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addSpaces() {
      this.inputValue = this.inputValue.replace(/(.{2})/g, "$1 ");
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

В этом примере, когда пользователь потеряет фокус с инпутом, значение будет обновляться с добавленными пробелами после двух символов. Вы можете изменить регулярное выражение, чтобы добавлять пробелы после трех символов вместо двух.

Comment: Если вы получаете ошибку с функцией replace, может быть проблема с тем, что значение инпута является null или undefined. Вы можете добавить проверку на это перед использованием replace, чтобы избежать ошибки. Например: `<template>
  <div>
    <input v-model.lazy="inputValue" @blur="addSpaces" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      inputValue: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addSpaces() {
      if (this.inputValue) {
        this.inputValue = this.inputValue.replace(/(.{2})/g, "$1 ");
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
`

Comment: Или использовать ternary operator : `this.inputValue = this.inputValue ? this.inputValue.replace(/(.{2})/g, "$1 ") : '';`  Это проверит значение инпута на null или undefined, и если это так, то ничего не будет делать. Если значение инпута является допустимым, то оно будет обрабатываться функцией replace.

Comment: Я нашел свою ошибку , я указывал в методе вашу переменную , а в v-model свою и из-за этого ругалось )

Comment: Не подскажите нотацию по replace , а то не могу сделать условие которое я хотел ?

Comment: Ну это уже могли бы погуглить))) если вы хотите добавить пробел после каждой группы из трех символов, вы можете использовать следующее регулярное выражение (.{3}) '.' - означает любой символ. {3} - означает количество символов, которые нужно сопоставить. Таким образом, выражение (.{3}) будет сопоставлять любую группу из трех символов. В твоем случае будет так this.inputValue = this.inputValue ? this.inputValue.replace(/(.{3})/g, "$1 ") : ''

Comment: Я хотел сделать вот так на примере 12 345 67 89, я не могу найти как сделать несколько групп

Comment: Надо было сразу написать как вы хотели.  попробуй так разделить числа replace(/(?<=\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, " ") заметь в кавычке должен быть пробел.